# Проверка существования ключа в Map

Tags: java, map

Необходимо в `HashMap` сохранить "ключ -> массив значений".

```
Map<Integer, List<Data>> myMap = new HashMap();
```

Если записи с таким номером нет, то заполняем `myMap`:

```
if (!myMap.containsKey(pos)) {
    List<Data> dataArray = new ArrayList();
    dataArray.add(new Data(a, b, c, d));
    myMap.put(pos, dataArray);
}
```

Далее идет снова проверка на существование, и если ключ есть, то выводим значение:

```
if (myMap.containsKey(pos)) 
    myMap.get(pos)
```

Проблема в том, что если при первой проверке ключа нет, то заполняется, однако второе условие тоже срабатывает. Но если заново вызвать функцию, содержащую эти проверки, то для `pos`, который, по идее, уже есть в `Map`, `containsKey` говорит, что якобы записи с ключом `pos` еще нет, и начинает заново заполнять `Map`. Но на самом деле такой ключ в `Map` уже есть. Как это исправить?

P.S. После добавления в `Map` `containsKey` показывает, что запись есть. `Map` у меня глобальный. И если вызвать `containsKey` в другом участке кода, то `containsKey` уже вернет `false` при том, что запись есть. Почему так, и как это исправить?

Comment: Все исправил смотрите снова

Comment: Если у вас многопоточное приложение, то вместо HashMap вам стоит использовать ConcurrentHashMap или другую потокобезопасную реализацию Map

Comment: Однопоточное.Просто нужно если данных нет в Map занести туда а потом оттуда брать.У меня получается постоянно заносятся и все.

Comment: Покажите где и как создается или откуда берется `pos`

Comment: @Barmaley  в вопросе показано все что откуда берется.Pos это позиция в списке и она всегда разная.

Comment: Что значит "Map у меня глобальный"? Из приведенных участков кода проблема не воспроизводится, очевидно она где то в других частях кода. Сделайте воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Собственно, да: приведенный код работает без проблем (при добавлении в код строк `int a = 10, b = 20, c = 30, d = 40; int pos = 2;`, ибо в вопросе значения не предоставлены), так что проблема, видимо, где-то в другом месте. Имеет смысл предоставить больше информации об этой самой функции и о том, как и где используется `myMap` в других участках кода.

Comment: @Regent  а вы в условии if (!myMap.containsKey(pos)) отладочное сообщение поставили?У меня говорит яко бы ключа нет.В общем в onDraw из БД при скроллинге получаю для определенной позиии cursor с данными.Да бы это дело что бы не тормозило решил если нет в map то добавить и уже курсо не звавть

Comment: @Ivan я второй `if` написал как `if (myMap.containsKey(pos)) System.out.println(myMap.get(pos).get(0).d);` и увидел на экране `40`.

Comment: Для второго то if срабатывает.Вы нажали на кнопку в цикле заполнили map.где i это pos.Далее еще раз жмете на кнопку и первый if говорит якобы pos такой нету.

Comment: @Ivan я никакие кнопки не жму, ибо в вопросе такого кода нет, а придумывать код в приступе телепатии не собираюсь. Повторюсь: в вопросе должен быть минимальный воспроизводимый пример код. У вас сейчас такого не предоставлено. Так что либо кто-то чудесным образом угадает что у вас за проблема где-то ещё, либо вопрос так и останется неотвеченным.

Comment: Вернусь к вопросу pavlofff, Map статический? Вы проверяли, на то что процесс ПРОВАЛИВАЕТСЯ в тело первой ифки или просто на условии точку остановки ставили?

Comment: Вопрос решил смотреть ответ

Answer (score 0):

У себя для похожей цели использую такой метод.

```
/**
 * @param checkMap мапа, куда необходимо добавить инфу
 * @param key      ключ для мапы выше, по которому ищем значения
 * @param value    значение, которое необходимо добавить
 * @param isSet    если true коллекция инициализируется как HashSet, иначе как ArrayList
 * @param <K>      Тип ключа
 * @param <V>      Тип значения
 * @return true если в мапе был данный ключ
 */
public static <K, V> boolean addToGroupMap(Map<K, Collection<V>> checkMap, K key, V value, boolean isSet) {
    assert checkMap != null;
    boolean result = false;

    Collection<V> vList = checkMap.get(key);
    if (vList == null) {
        vList = isSet ? new HashSet<V>() : new ArrayList<V>();
        vList.add(value);
        checkMap.put(key, vList);
    } else {
        vList.add(value);
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```